# How does one parse a string into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) directly instead of to a CST (Concrete Syntax Tree)?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, compilers, parsers, syntax-trees

I wanted to parse strings to AST data structures instead of CSTs - which introduce a lot of intermediate nodes like terminal that might not be needed. I am not sure if one first creates a CST and then trims the CST somehow to generate an AST. This seems that should be a well solved problem so I didn't want to be adhoc about my particular grammars or CSTs to generate the AST. I assume or hope there is something else.

How does one do it?

For the simplest example I could think of consider simply typed lambda calc [in the python Lark parser](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/issues/1053):

```
term : "λ" term ":" type "." term
    | "[" term term "]"
    | /[A-Za-z0-9_]+/
type : type "->" type  // "->"
    | /[A-Za-z0-9_]+/
// ignore tokens
IGNORE_TOKENS : "(" | ")"
%import common.WS
%ignore WS
%ignore IGNORE_TOKENS
// %import common.ESCAPED_STRING
// %import common.SIGNED_NUMBER
```

What are the tools to convert strings in simply type lambda calc to data structures with or trees with Abs, Apply, Var etc?

**What I really want are ASTs not CSTs from a string.**

---

Related:

- https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/issues/1053